# JS doesnt work after adding Content-Security-Policy / content=default-src https:

Tags: javascript, https, content-security-policy

Hi My Site works fine (bureaudonald.com). Only one JS isnt working anymore after adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https:">`

This is the code. Does anybody know what I have to change to make it work?

```js
function GetValue()
 {
  var myarray= new Array(
   "Why are we doing this?",
   "Why are we making this?",
   "Why would we add this?",
   "etc"
   );
     var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
 }
```

```html
 <!-- WHY -->
 <div class="main why_loader" id="whysection"> 
 
  <section data-navlink="navwhy">
   
  <div class="why">
  
   <div class="why_content">
   
    <div class="why_field">
     <span class="why_title" id="message">Ask Why!<br/>And Ask it Again<br/>And again</span>
    </div>        
   
    <div class="why_button">
     <button class="why_btn" onclick="GetValue();">Ask Why Again!</button>
    </div>
   
   </div>
   <h2>&nbsp;</h2>    
  </div>
     
  </section>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). Source: onsubmit attribute on DIV element.
bureaudonald.com  and so  on...

Comment: That is your problem.  You need to remove the unsafe scripts.

Comment: Yes, my question is how to make my script in this post safe.

Comment: Move all code from inline event handlers to `addEventListener()`.